# How to set<Input> submit button to size of text

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm using jquery mobile and have a form with a submit button.  Unfortunately, after doing some research I learned that jquery mobile's data-inline attribute doesn't work for input elements.  I want the submit button to just be the size of its text.  Firefox must take care of this, because the button is the size I want it to be.  However, IE sets the width of the button to the size of the container.  Any way to style a submit button to the size of its text and no larger?  I tried doing:

```
$('#element').css('display','inline')
```

That didn't work, though.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where do you expect your mobile site being viewed in IE?

Comment: @ZoltanToth I think it's that we're also using this as a desktop application (if that makes sense).  Otherwise, you're right it wouldn't matter.

Comment: Then you might want try to set all the parameters to match an inline element - `$('#element').css({ display : 'inline !important', padding: 0, margin: 0, width: 'auto' })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo of a `<input type="button" />` element that correctly goes to "inline" when you add the `data-inline="true"` attribute to it (this is tested in IE8/IE9): http://jsfiddle.net/eVTef/

To fix this in IE7 you need to add the "inline hack":

```
.ui-btn-inline {
    *display : inline !important;
    zoom     : 1;
}
```

The property prefixed by an asterisk (`*`) will not be read by IE8/IE9 or any other modern browsers but will be read by IE7. The `zoom : 1` has to be added so the element gets the `hasLayout` CSS (which cannot be manually added to an element).

Here is a demo of the above fix: http://jsfiddle.net/eVTef/1/

**Bonus Round**

You can also fix this issue in IE6 but you will need to specify a height for the element. To specify a height for just IE6 and no other browsers we can do something similar to the asterisk hack for IE7:

```
.ui-btn-inline {
    *display : inline !important;
    zoom     : 1;
    _height  : 30px;
}
```

Even IE7 will disregard the underscore (`_`) prefixed property but IE6 will use the property declaration.

Comment: what is the meaning of `*` here? can you please explain that & why it works?

Comment: I have a feeling I was typing that exact answer when you commented. Check the answer now.

Comment: I'm assuming that you are talking about IE7, if not you should post what version you're testing with.

Comment: @Jasper This works, but it affects other buttons all ready created.  When I try to just add the code for this input element, it doesn't work.

Comment: This may help explain: http://flipc.blogspot.com/2009/02/damn-ie7-and-inline-block.html

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the text in a `<span>` tag, and calculate the width of that.

see example: http://jsbin.com/oxocil/2/edit

edit: you could also add the span tag via javascript, and then remove it the same way if necessary.

Comment: I believe that this is a jQuery Mobile specific issue because it's regarding the CSS applied via jQuery Mobile.